# ¿Cómo se puede escapar todos los carácteres con Javascript incluido letras?

Tags: javascript, html

Intentaré hacer la pregunta lo más clara posible. Esto `%3C%70%3E%48%6F%6C%61%3C%2F%70%3E` es igual a `<p>Hola</p>`, que según creo, es escapar texto. En este caso, `encodeURIComponent()` escapa símbolos, pero no letras, como se puede ver en el ejemplo. Lo que quiero es que todo tipo de carácter, ya sea letra o símbolo, me lo devuelva escapado. Por lo tanto, ¿qué código de Javascript tengo que tener para que, al insertar `<p>Hola</p>` (puede ser cualquier tipo de código, no específicamente ese) en un cuadro de texto y pulsar un botón, me lo devuelva de esta manera `%3C%70%3E%48%6F%6C%61%3C%2F%70%3E` y no esta `%3Cp%3EHola%3C%2Fp%3E` que es la que ocurre en el ejemplo? Creo que es algo de hexadecimales. Gracias de antemano

```html
<p>Click the button to encode a URI.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var uri = "<p>Hola</p>";
  var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamente has dado en el clavo, es un valor en [hexadecimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_hexadecimal) que representa el carácter alfanumérico (`[A-Z], [a-z], [0-9]`) en una [tabla ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

El método [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent), efectivamente deja por fuera (no codifica) los siguientes elementos:

- Caracteres alfabéticos: `[A-Z], [a-z]`
- Caracteres numéricos: `[0-9]`
- Los siguientes caracteres: `- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

Si lo que deseas es escribir tu propia función, puedes hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
function customEncode() {
  let uri = "<p>Hola</p>";
  let encoded = uri.split('').map(char => {
    return `%${char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()}`;
  }).join('');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = encoded;
}

document.getElementById('encode').addEventListener('click', customEncode);
```

```html
<p>Click the button to encode a URI.</p>
<button id="encode" type="button">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Y aunque ya te han respondido, dejo mi solución estilo `one-liner`.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas es obtener el valor hexadecimal de cada carácter y anteponerle `%`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function toURLHex(str) {
  return str.split('').map(v => '%' + v.charCodeAt().toString(16)).join('');
}

let enc = toURLHex('<p>Hola</p>');
let dec = decodeURIComponent(enc);
console.log(enc, '=', dec);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que crear una función que vaya recorriendo cada caracter del `string` para que te devuelva su valor **Unicode** e ir concatenándole el símbolo de porcentaje.

```js
String.prototype.hexEncode = function(){
    var hex, i;

    var result = "";
    for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += ("%"+hex).slice(-4);
    }

    return result
}

var str = "<p>Hola</p>";
console.log(str.hexEncode());
```

**Adaptación de:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648161/10268956

Comment: Los chinos también tienen derecho a tener representación Unicode de sus caracteres ^^

Comment: Me refiero a que la función `charCodeAt()` obtiene el código Unicode de cualquier caracter, luego si este es chino, cirílico o etrusco no afecta al resultado. No hace falta que estés a la defensiva, tan solo bromeaba ^^