# ¿Qué código tengo que insertar de Javascript para escapar a Escape sequences?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Qué código tengo que insertar dentro de `miaccion()` para que el texto sea escapado a Escape Sequences Unicode, es decir, de esta manera `\u0073\u006F\u0020\u0074\u0068\u0061\u0074`?

```js
function miaccion() {

}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Escribe aquí la palabra..." id="palabras" />
<button onclick="miaccion()">Escapara a Escape Sequence Unicode</button>
```

Comment: Te pregunta abarca algo muy amplio, cuando tengas un problema en **específico**, puedes plantear de nuevo tu pregunta (editandola), te adjunto [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para  que te informes acerca del tema. Saludos.

Comment: Al contrario de *amplia*, me parece que no has intentado nada, deberías mostrar lo que has investigado. Sin usar ningún lenguaje, ¿sabes lo que significan los caracteres [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)? ¿Has investigado cómo pueden convertirse u obtenerse los valores en hexadecimal de los caracteres? Recuerdo haberte respondido un pregunta sobre el tema. Creo que deberías empezar por intentar implementar algo por tu propia cuenta. Saludos

Comment: Necesito más información: que necesitas hacer con lo escapado? Por ejemplo esto: ´console.log("\u0073\u006F\u0020\u0074\u0068\u0061\u0074")´ saca "so that" en consola.

Comment: @enxaneta ese es el mayor problema, que un texto escapado así, siempre será convertido a su representación codificada. La verdad es que yo tampoco logro entender el propósito de esto.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Creo que su intencion es mantener tal cual esa codificacion para mostrarla, es decir que no se conviertan esos caracteres a su representacion codificada, eso es posible, pero tocara esperar a que el usuario nos de mas informacion al respecto de lo que realmente quiere hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que aquello que deseas es que se te muestre la sentencia de caracteres unicode en vez de que se te muestre directamente el resultado de la sentencia de caracteres unicode, y ademas, según pienso, deseas que el resultado sea lo que el usuario introdució pero en formato unicode, es decir, **un traductor a unicode**, asi que pense en lo siguiente:

```js
function miaccion(palabra) {
  let palabraUnicode = "";
  
  palabra.split("").forEach((p, i) => {
    palabraUnicode += `\\u${palabra.charCodeAt(i).toString(0x10).padStart(4, "0")}`;
  });
  console.log(palabraUnicode);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Escribe aquí la palabra..." id="palabras" />
<button onclick="miaccion(palabras.value)">Escapara a Escape Sequence Unicode</button>
```

Para entender lo que he hecho vamos por partes, primero voy a decir que cosas he cambiado en tu codigo principal que son primordiales, en primeras está ésta parte de aquí en el html:

```
<button onclick="miaccion(palabras.value)">Escapara a Escape Sequence Unicode</button>
```

como veras ahora a `miaccion` le mandamos como parametro el valor o contenido que tiene el input con `id` **palabras**, que seria el valor de este input de aqui:

```
<input placeholder="Escribe aquí la palabra..." id="palabras" />
```

Lo segundo que hecho es que ahora le he indicado a la funcion `miaccion` que reciba un nuevo parametro, al parametro le he llamado `palabra`:

```
function miaccion(palabra) {
  //
}
```

Lo tercero que he hecho es que le he añadido a tu función llamada `miaccion` cierto código, código el cual sirve para el propósito que necesitas, en tu caso convertir una secuencia de caracteres a unicode, así que primero crearemos una variable que almacenara el resultado de la traducción de toda tu cadena a unicode, a esta variable yo le he llamado `palabraUnicode`:

```
let palabraUnicode = "";
```

Luego mas adelante usamos el parametro de nuestra funcion para iterar por cada una de las letras de la palabra, pero **para poder iterarlas hay que tener un array**.

por este motivo he usado:

```
palabra.split("")
```

Ya que de esa manera obligamos a que se cree un arreglo en orden que contendra en cada espacio un caracter de nuestra palabra, en pocas palabras convertimos una cadena de texto en un array de caracteres.

Luego al resultado de ese split, como se trata de un array lo podremos iterar con un `forEach`, el cual es otro de los muchos ciclos que hay en `javascript`, `forEach` toma como parametro principal un callback, es decir una función la cual ejecutara el `forEach` por cada iteración, este seria nuestro callback:

```
(p, i) => {
    //
}
```

Eso de ahi se conoce como **funcion flecha** o **arrow function**, fueron introducidas en **ES6** y son muy utiles para acortar muchisimo nuestro codigo, tambien tienen sus propias peculiaridades, pero hacen las vecez de una `function`.

Si deseas mirar mas información al respecto en la descripcion dejare un enlace para que puedas consultar en mayor profundidad sobre las **arrow functions**.

Muy bien, entonces la estructura basica de nuestro `forEach` queda de esta manera:

```
palabra.split("").forEach((p, i) => {
  //Cuerpo del callback del forEach
});
```

El callback del `forEach` puede recibir **tres parametros**, estos tres parametros son automaticos, y los provee el mismo `forEach`, tu solo te encargarias de mencionarle al `forEach` cuales vas a usar y como los vas a llamar, el primero (`p`) seria el valor actual del arreglo que esta siendo recorrido, el segundo seria el indice numérico actual, y el tercero (el cual no puse porque era innecesario pero puedes ponerlo), se trata del array entero, al cual puedes llamar de otra forma.

Asi que dentro del cuerpo del `forEach` tenemos:

```
palabraUnicode += `\\u${palabra.charCodeAt(i).toString(0x10).padStart(4, "0")}`;
```

Recordemos que cuando usamos el simbolo `+` seguido de un signo igual (`=`) significa que haremos algo llamado **concatenacion**, este concepto de concatenación solo aplica para strings, ya que de ser números no seria concatenación, seria una suma.

Veamos un ejemplo de concatenación mas claro antes de proseguir con lo demas:

```js
let res = "hola";
let p2 = " mundo";

res += p2;
console.log(res);
```

El resultado es que `res` contiene la concatenacion entre `hola` y  `mundo`, dandonos como resultado la cadena `"hola mundo"`, y todo esto fue posible debido a la concatenacion (`+=`).

Si solo hubiesemos usado el signo `=` hubiese sucedido lo siguiente:

```js
let res = "hola";
let p2 = " mundo";

res = p2;
console.log(res);
```

Por lo tanto es imprescindible que en vez de hacer una **asignacion** (`=`), hagamos una **concatenacion** (`+=`).

Muy bien, sigamos, del lado derecho del `+=` tenemos:

```
`\\u${palabra.charCodeAt(i).toString(0x10).padStart(4, "0")}`;
```

Quiza eso te confunda, porque hay varias operaciones juntas, y ademas se estan usando conceptos que quiza te sean nuevos, por lo tanto voy a explicar parte por parte, en primeras decir que desde **ES6** existe algo llamado **template strings**, o tambien llamadas **plantillas de cadenas de texto** las cuales permiten renderizar codigo javascript directamente en una cadena de texto.

**NOTA**: para poder usar la **interpolacion** de un template string se deben usar unas comillas especiales llamadas **backticks**, las cuales se ven asi: `.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo de template strings para que quede mas claro lo que hay arriba y que no nos confundamos:

```js
const nombre = "juan";
const edad = 20;
const res = `Hola mi nombre es ${nombre} y tengo ${edad} años!`;

console.log(res);
```

Como vemos, para poder renderizar por ejemplo variables dentro de un `template string`, debemos encerrar el nombre de nuestra variable dentro de `${}`, pero recuerda, **los templates strings tambien pueden ejecutar codigo javascript**, por lo tanto, **parte** de este largo fragmento de aqui:

```
`\\u${palabra.charCodeAt(i).toString(0x10).padStart(4, "0")}`;
```

Es codigo javascript que esta siendo renderizado en un `template string` de manera directa.

asi que repasamos ahora desde el inicio de nuevo, primero tenemos:

```
\\
```

Lo que ocurre es que para escapar caracteres especiales como por ejemplo comillas simples `'`, comillas dobles `"`, backticks ` o incluso barras invertidas (`\`) se usa el caracter (`\`), en este caso como deseamos escapar la barra invertida deberemos escaparla con otra barra invertida `\`, de esta manera la primera servira para escapar la segunda y ademas la primera no sera mostrada.

Luego tenemos `u`, que representa uno de los inicios de una cadena unicode (`\u`).

Lo siguiente seria codigo javascript renderizado en el template string:

```
${palabra.charCodeAt(i).toString(0x10).padStart(4, "0")}
```

Que equivale a :

- **palabra.charCodeAt(i)**: obten el codigo unicode en base decimal de el caracter en la pocision `i` (pocision actual recorrida en el `forEach`).
- **toString(0x10)**: como lo anterior no tiene el formato deseado y ademas tu unicode se encuentra en `base16` entonces convierteme lo anterior en un `string` en **base16** o **hexadecimal**.
- **padStart(4, "0")**: si el unicode en **base16** obtenido anteriormente no tiene longitud `4` en sus digitos rellename la cadena al inicio con ceros de tal forma que la longitud en los digitos siempre sea de `4`.

Por ultimo tenemos:

```
console.log(palabraUnicode);
```

Que imprimira en consola el resultado de la traduccion a `unicode` de la cadena.

Comment: Aqui el enlace a la explicacion de funciones flecha o arrow functions: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363155/explicaci%c3%b3n-de-funciones-flecha-en-javascript

Comment: Te doy +1 por el esfuerzo y dedicación en la respuesta. Sin embargo, considero que el OP no ha demostrado un intento claro en resolver el problema, sobretodo cuando tiene una [pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367548/cómo-se-puede-escapar-todos-los-carácteres-con-javascript-incluido-letras) con respuesta aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Saludos,  Riven por tu dedicación, al final lo he conseguido. Dirigiendome ahora a @MauricioContreras Primero ¿supongo que OP te refieres a mí? ¿Qué es OP? Segundo, si no he podido contestar antes, como por ejemplo a tu último comentario en la parte de arriba es porque he estado indispuesto. Los comentarios como el tuyo suenan mordaces

Comment: @Programandosiempre no te lo tomes personal, debemos tratar de mantener la calidad en el sitio, es la idea en general y sí, a veces mis comentarios son bastante directos. En cuanto a OP, viene del inglés, si mal no recuerdo son las siglas de `Original Poster`, en alusión a quién formuló la pregunta originalmente. Saludos